# Newcommand with different definitions depending on the value of one argument

Tags: conditionals, optional-arguments

I am writing some stats notes, and I have to type null and alternative Hypothesis quite often, so I thought having a command that does it for me would be nice

Basically I want to get something that if I type `\hnull[55]{g}` it gives me `H_a^{}:\: \mu\,\geq\,55`, but if I type `\hnull[55]{l}` it gives `H_a^{}:\: \mu\,\leq\,55`, and for `\hnull[55]{n}` I get `H_a^{}:\: \mu\,\neq\,55`. 
Ideally I would like it to be so that if the optional argument is empty, it prints `\mu_0^{}` in its place.

I've been looking around the documentation, and I tried playing with `xparse` but the examples I found check if the (optional) argument is empty, not if it's equal to something.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \hnull { o m } {%
  \IfNoValueTF {#1} {%
    \mathlarger{H}_0^{}:\:\mu #2 \mu_0^{}%
  }{%
    \mathlarger{H}_0^{}:\:\mu #2 #1%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[\hnull[55]{\leq}\]
\[\hnull{\geq}\]
\[\hnull{\neq}\]
\[\hnull{\leq}\]

\end{document}
```

but it is an inelegant solution to my problem, it would be nicer to just type `g` instead of `\geq`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple with no check for the first argument:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\hnull}{ O{\mu_0} m }
 {%
  H_0:\mu\hnullsymbol{#2}#1%
 }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hnullsymbol}{m}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {g}{\geq}
    {l}{\leq}
    {n}{\neq}
   }
   { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\hnull[55]{l} \\
\hnull{g} \\
\hnull{n} \\
\hnull[33]{=} \\
\hnull{<}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

The `\mathlarger` serves no purpose and the additional spacings you have only make the thing less readable, in my opinion.

[image]

Comment: This looks so nice and simple, once knowing the syntax. Any reading you recommend to learn the syntax for this level of programming with Latex?

Answer (score 5):

The following conditions on your choice of `g`, `l` and `n` for `\geq`, `\leq` and `\neq`. If you supply an empty mandatory argument (or nothing is matched), the result is `=`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand \hnull { o m } {%
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {
    \str_case:nnF { #2 }
      {
        { g } { \geq }
        { l } { \leq }
        { n } { \neq }
      }
      { = }
  }
  \IfValueTF {#1} {
    H \c_math_subscript_token 0:\:\mu \l_tmpa_tl #1
  }{
    H \c_math_subscript_token 0:\:\mu \l_tmpa_tl \mu \c_math_subscript_token 0
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\hnull[55]{l}$

$\hnull{g}$

$\hnull{n}$

$\hnull{l}$

$\hnull{}$

\end{document}
```